# Conditionally Set Bootstrap Form Select Tag Selected with Embedded Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Bootstrap's form select tag, and I want to set the initially selected option conditionally with embedded ruby, based on the value of some variable.

I have found a solution using jquery and javascript, described at this website: https://www.daftlogic.com/information-programmatically-preselect-dropdown-using-javascript.htm, where you loop through the potential options, and then set the selected value. However, I was wondering if there was another approach, where one can use embedded ruby to render the selected option on the initial render.

Here is the HTML with the selected tag:

```
<select>
    <option name="project-option">General Search</option>
    <% current_user.projects.each do |project| %>
      <option name="project-option" id="project-option-<%= project.id %>"><%= project.name %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you post the related html.erb file?

Comment: Also, I think default Bootstrap Dropdowns don't actually have a 'selected' logic. (see https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/) Maybe what you're using is a bootstrap from 'Select' component?

Comment: Hi @Ideld. Sorry, you are right. Its a bootstrap form select tag. I've updated my question